# saving changes in fedora live usb

Tags: usb, fedora, usb-flash-drive, persistent

I recently installed Fedora 12 on my USB drive. But I am not able to save the changes I do in a live session.  I created 2 users and put some icons in desktop... But after I restarted Fedora from the live usb, the changes could not be seen.

Can anybody suggest what to do to save the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recently installed fedora 12 on my
>   USB drive

Did you install or copy the Live CD ISO onto the flash disk ? Seems like you copied the live CD ISO onto the flash disk than installed it.

You need to create a Live USB with persistence mode, have a look at [this article](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD/USBHowTo) for instructions on how to do so.